# error running rosrun command

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running catkin on Mac OS X, and build a project given in tutorial, when i run `catkin_make`, it build successfully without giving error.

but when i run `rosrun first_tutorial talker` command it gives me following error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: librospack.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ankurkhandelwal/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin/rospack
  Reason: image not found
find: ftsopen: No such file or directory
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below 
find: ftsopen: No such file or directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223475/error-running-rosrun-command/) by [ankur_27](https://answers.ros.org/users/25475/ankur_27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried running this?

```
rospack profile
```

This should crawl your workspace and update the list of available packages for *rosrun*

**[UPDATE]**

Looking better at your report, it looks like your are having problems with DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can find the fix in this github comment: https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/12#issuecomment-149336634. I'll copy-paste it here for reference:

> **quick-and-dirty fix** for this (for
> anyone else having trouble) was to add

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/ros/indigo/lib
```

> to the start of ***/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosrun***, which resolves the issue.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ankur_27](https://answers.ros.org/users/25475/ankur_27/) on 2016-01-06**:
@martin...i have run rospack but still same error